# SharePoint Online: How to flag file when file was Downloaded by UI/UX

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have research a lot about this theme (Microsoft Docs, Forums etc.), but I cannot encounter something to help me: I need some UI/UX resource like a flag or check to mark all files was Downloaded. SharePoint List/Library contains some hide column, metadata or native resource that shows if File was Downloaded?

Please, may someone help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To follow answer of this question, see the link at SharePoint Stack Exchange: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/294065/sharepoint-online-how-to-flag-file-when-file-was-downloaded-by-ui-ux

With the urgency of this demand, the question was replicated in both forums.